# How Long Does It Take For All Champions To Rotate Through "Free To Play"?

Tags: league-of-legends

Given the selection of free-to-play champions changes regularly, how long does it take for all champions to rotate the list? An important piece of information I don't know is whether or not a champ can be free again before all other champs have been free.

Comment: I'm not sure this can have a definitive answer as the free champs are picked randomly and not sequentially. Also as more champs are released this will only get longer. so the question will become out of date very quickly.

Comment: That's the answer I was expecting, but I wanted there to be a firm answer here.

Comment: Note that newly released champion show a pattern of going into free rotation approximately 2-3 weeks after they release.

Comment: I disagree that the question is too broad. The accepted answer has all of the relevant information, and, frankly, the answer is simple and straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 119 Champions right now (Braum Patch) and if we take a look at the [champion cotation of season 4](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Champion_Rotation_Schedule_%28Season_Four%29) and take Karma as an example, we see that Karma was free in the first, 8th and 14th week of season 4. On the other hand there is Amumu only appearing at the 12th week. This tells us that champions for the rotation are picked almost completely random and also tells us, that champions can be free, even if the rotation is not complete (through all 119 champions).

[There are six different 'types' of champions](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Free_champion_rotation): Assassin, Mage, Fighter, Marksman, Support and Tank; and Riot tries to have a balanced rotation, meaning they want to have atleast five of the six types in the rotation. Often there are all six types represented, and very rarely only four.

Additionally it is very likely that about three to five champions of the rotation are strong in the current meta and ofttimes one of those is considered overpowered.

**In the end you won't be able to predict when a particular champion will be free**, but if a champion didn't occur for 15 or more weeks, he will most likely be available in the next few weeks.

Answer (score 1):

The truth is, it can be unpredictable, like has been previously mentioned. However, it is not random. Some champions are easier/simpler to play, and Riot will recycle those champions much more often in the free pool for beginning players. One of their goals is so that you can play every champion eventually and they aim to provide you with a balance of different types of champions.

[Riot actually made a post about exactly how they choose free week champions here.](http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=46045)